# How to write a single unit test that can test both ASMX and WCF web services

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, asmx

I am using Visual Studio 2010 C# to unit test ASMX web services. I have added a web service reference to my unit Test project. Each unit test invokes methods on the ASMX web service under test and validates its responses which are in XML.

In addition to the ASMX webservices, we have a parallel development of WCF web services which are functionally identical to their ASMX counter parts.

My aim is to use the same battery of unit tests to test both ASMX and WCF services. What is the best way to switch between the two types of web services without having to duplicate my unit tests code. I would also like to avoid any manual steps during the switch over from ASMX to WCF and visa versa. Ideally, I'd like to test my full suite of tests for both ASMX and WCF under a single TFS Test plan run.

Any thouhts?

Comment: If you are testing more than one thing, it is not a unit test.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment from Oded that this is a bad idea.

Having said that, I'll remind you that you can use a Service Reference to point to an ASMX service. In this way, all of your proxy classes will follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

refactor your current method to take the location of either the asmx page or the wcf path and create two new tests that call the refactored method and pass the appropriate url